# Child and Parent Window Information Exchange

Tags: javascript, html, window, parent

I'm currently writing a Bookmarklet which checks the code of the current webpage and than displays the results in a Pop-up Window.
I have 2 js files: One (lets call it tests.js) makes the checks and opens the popup window (a new html-page).
The other one makes some dynamic changes to the popup html file which links to the JavaScript File popup.js.

My Problem is, I can't access any of the variables I declared in test.js in the popup.js File.
I tried the window.opener Method, but it doesn't work because of the same-origin-policy:

```
if(window.opener.myVar==false){}
```

I also tried the other way around, by accessing the DOM of the Pop-Up window from the tests.js file:

```
  var checks=  Popup.document.getElementById('Checks');
```

This does not work either.
Is there an Easy way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `window.postMessage`